# Xamarin: is it possible to know the hardware status

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, hardware, diagnostics

I would like to know if there is a way to diagnose device hardware through a Xamarin app? (status of the bluetooth, wifi, battery, ...) I don't want to know if these elements are enabled or disabled, but I need to have a "lower" level of information, such as during an Apple diagnosis.

For basic informations (like manufacturer, model, ...) I've seen that there is the [DeviceInfoPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin) from James Montemagno.

I would like to create a basic app that allow to diagnose these elements on iOS and Android...

Answer (score 0):

At least on the iOS side, the answer is probably "no". It depends on exactly what info you want, but most detailed system info is either not available to apps (usually for security reasons) or only available via private APIs (meaning if you tried to put this in the app store, it would be rejected). Android is more liberal with its system data though, so possibly doable there.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I would like to get information about device (manufacturer, model), screen (size, resolution), battery (state, wear), and wifi / bluetooth / speaker (broken or not). It does not seem to be possible according to your comment, or only on Android.